# Can't write DBNull to SQL in Powershell

Tags: null, powershell

In Powershell, I have some data that I am importing from a `.csv`, and some data points aren't always entered so I need to replace them with `[DBNull]::Value`.

The problem is that when I go to use `Write-SqlTableData` I get this error:

`Write-SqlTableData : Invalid storage type: DBNull.`

I'm using this code to detect blank spaces and replace them with `DBNull`'s:

```
$DataOut | Foreach-Object {
    ForEach ($Property in $_.PSObject.Properties) {
        If([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($Property.Value)) {
            $_.($Property.Name) = [DBNull]::Value
        }
    }
}
```

What is the issue here? What is an alternative?

Comment: An alternative: [use write-dbadatatable](https://dbatools.io/functions/write-dbadatatable/) it will take care of the nulls for you.

Comment: @Shawn Melton , awesome statement in comments. Give the answer to OP rather than comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am having the exactly the same issue and I come to this web page. But it really did not solve the issue other than what Shawn Metlton mentioned to use write-dbadatatable in the comment.

Since the original poster @discipline did not give the whole PS script, I cannot fix his issue. But I figure out how to do the work after one hour's try.

So here is how to repeat the same error message

We first create a table in [TempDB] on my local sql server instance

```
use tempdb
if object_id('dbo.t', 'U') is not null
    drop table dbo.t;
create table dbo.t (name varchar(100), gender varchar(10), id int)
```

Now we write a few lines of PS codes as follows:

```
$p = [pscustomobject] @{name='jeffrey'; gender='male'; city='Toronto'}
#this can be successful
Write-SqlTableData -ServerInstance localhost -DatabaseName tempdb -SchemaName dbo -TableName t -InputData $p;
```

After execution, we can check the sql table and see it is indeed successful as shown below

[image]

Now if we change the $p to have its [city] property to DBNull as the following

```
$p = [pscustomobject] @{name='jeffrey'; gender='male'; city=[dbnull]::Value}
#this will fail
Write-SqlTableData -ServerInstance localhost -DatabaseName tempdb -SchemaName dbo -TableName t -InputData $p;
```

we can see the following error

[image]

The alternative solution is to create a [system.data.datatable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) and then pass the object value to this datatable and then pass datatable to write-sqltabledata as shown below

```
$dt = new-object 'System.Data.DataTable';
$dt.Columns.Add((new-object System.Data.DataColumn('name', [System.String])));
$dt.Columns.Add((new-object System.Data.DataColumn('gender', [System.String])));
$dt.Columns.Add((new-object System.Data.DataColumn('city', [System.String])));

$p = [pscustomobject] @{name='jeffrey'; gender='male'; city=[dbnull]::Value}

$p | % {$r = $dt.NewRow(); $r.name=$_.name; $r.gender=$_.gender; $r.city=$_.city; $dt.rows.add($r);}
#this will succeed
Write-SqlTableData -ServerInstance localhost -DatabaseName tempdb -SchemaName dbo -TableName t -InputData $dt;
```

Now if we query the sql table again, we will see it works

[image]

If you have other better ideas, please share for the commuity.

Comment: Is that an actual null entry, or just the word NULL? There is usually a faint yellow background for a null entry.

Comment: It is really null, not a literal word "NULL"

Comment: So how do we handle this for a CSV with thousands of rows where any number of them might be null? Setting the value to null for each row is not feasible.